# crontab in mac is not working properly for python script

Tags: python, cron

```
crontab -l:

(base) yan@0053 notebooks % crontab -l
* * * * * /opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/yan/Documents/pol/coop/analysis/test.py
* * * * * echo "hello" >>/Users/yan/Documents/pol/coop/analysis/hello.txt

Does NOT work in crobtab: 
* * * * * /opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/yan/Documents/pol/coop/analysis/test.py

Does work in crontab:
* * * * * echo "hello" >>/Users/yan/Documents/pol/coop/analysis/hello.txt


BUT this python script works in Terminal, and i have the output file saved in the folder: 
(base) yan@0053 notebooks % /opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/yan/Documents/pol/coop/analysis/test.py
```

I am wondering how to debug python.py in crontab. I can't manually run it in terminal...

My test.py:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
                   'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']})
df.to_csv('ouoput.csv', index=False)
```

Basically, shouldn't be a test.py issue, cuz I simply modified the test.py and only include one line print('y'). It works in manually, but doesn't work in crontab

```
print('y')
```

This issue was resolved by https://blog.bejarano.io/fixing-cron-jobs-in-mojave/

Comment: Does your test.py create output? If so, where will that end up...?

Comment: To be clear: does `df.to_csv('/Users/yan/Documents/polarr/coop/analysis/ouoput.csv', index=False)` work?

Comment: df.to_csv('/Users/yan/Documents/polarr/coop/analysis/ouoput.csv', index=False) work?   --- yes, work.   have a ouoput.csv saved @Roadowl

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?  The file `ouoput.csv` should be created in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS CronTab has been deprecated since 10.4. It's not supported. I recommend shifting away from Crontab to launchd. In short, you create .plist files with your instructions. There's this excellent little app called LaunchControl that's super helpful for running background system scripts and processes. Highly recommend since the syntax and permissions / security settings can be tricky. Also, there's this great little article "How to Use launchd to Run Services in macOS."

Comment: Thanks @nwood21.  I am curious that echo did work in crontab, why the python script doesn't work in the crontab?

Comment: Hi nwood21, i fouond this https://blog.bejarano.io/fixing-cron-jobs-in-mojave/, and this issue got resolved

Comment: Great info on cron in Mac. Although reading this: "Warning: this is not a great idea security-wise, if a malicious actor can create cron jobs or edit the scripts ran as cron jobs, he or she would have Full Disk Access too. Monitor the system’s installed cron jobs manually or with a tool such as KnockKnock and proceed with caution." I suppose you would want to be careful with 3rd party applications not on the App store installing scripts that can run malicious code.